# memcached session server cache miss/ hit count commnad

Tags: memcached

I am trying to configure magento session management with memcached server. I have install memcached and also its client and configure my magento local.xml file under etc folder as below. My memcached server is listening on 11211 default port.

magento store front is working good with memcached correctly.

I am curious to find out the statistics of memcached server. How may cache session miss/hit happen on server and other statistcs too. I have used the following command to see it

$ echo "stats settings" | nc localhost 11211

```
STAT maxbytes 67108864
STAT maxconns 1024
STAT tcpport 11211
STAT udpport 11211
STAT inter 127.0.0.1
STAT verbosity 0
STAT oldest 0
STAT evictions on
STAT domain_socket NULL
STAT umask 700
STAT growth_factor 1.25
STAT chunk_size 48
STAT num_threads 4
STAT stat_key_prefix :
STAT detail_enabled no
STAT reqs_per_event 20
STAT cas_enabled yes
STAT tcp_backlog 1024
STAT binding_protocol auto-negotiate
STAT auth_enabled_sasl no
STAT item_size_max 1048576
END
```

Can any one help me to find out what commands or procedure i 'll use to see my memcached daemon cache miss/hit.

Comment: probably better posting this on serverfault.com

Answer (score 0):

There's a really nice tool that will show you all the stats you need :

http://code.google.com/p/phpmemcacheadmin/

Really easy to install and configure.